# Disable the close button when bounty is active

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I tried to close a question. I clicked the "close" link, *after* I entered a custom reason and *after* I finally hit the button, it showed the error message

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

[image: This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed]

If it's not possible to close the question, could we disable the "close" link in advance then or leave the link enabled and show the message earlier?

From UX perspective, the late message is a surprise which violates POLS (principle of least surprise). The user actions to get there result in a violation of the rule of low (physical) action.

Comment: Agreed.. it seems like this would also save two unnecessary AJAX requests too.

Comment: I had the same problem today with an off-topic. Also wondered then what the point of a bounty on an off-topic question was. Better to refund and close, I'd have thought.

Comment: I believe the rationale here is that leaving it enabled doubly serves as an explanation. If it's disabled, then we'll get people coming to meta asking why. Personally I think it's fine the way it is. Presumably before you clicked the button, you did not know you could not close a question with a bounty and now you do know. So as far as I can tell it's working.

Comment: @Radiodef Though the error message only appeared *after* the close reason was selected and a custom one was entered.  It would make more sense to have the message appear immediately upon clicking the close button.

Comment: Here on meta, the edit link is disabled if you don't have enough rep, with a tooltip which says that suggested edits are not allowed on meta. Maybe this could work the same way ?

Comment: I believe the same happens to flagging the bountied question, and it was confusing too.

Comment: Surely just replace the close button with a message giving the reason why it can't be closed. Just on the page.

Answer (score -6):

While this may make sense, it doesn't really follow the typical Stack Exchange UX principles.

Stack Exchange sites don't like to hide things from you; if you click on an element that you can't really do anything with at the time, you'll be told why, but if that element isn't there in the first place, you may be left wondering why.

Examples include allowing you to go through the close dialog process [only to find out that you're out of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237926/why-let-me-flag-a-post-if-youre-not-going-to-let-me-flag-it) (or flags) and [showing you pending reviews in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes) even after you're out of reviews.

You can also see a similar behavior on locked questions, where comments are "not eligible for voting or flagging," but have vote and flag buttons nonetheless.

In fact, the only exception I can think of to this rule is also present on locked posts – the vote buttons on the question and its answers are hidden.

Comment: If I'm reading the OP correctly, it sounds like they didn't see an error until after entering a close reason, which IMHO is a bit late.  We could instead display the error immediately on clicking close.  That wouldn't require hiding the close link.

Comment: @Kevin True (and personally, I think that's better), but if we're sticking to standards, that's the same way it works with close voting when you have no votes.

Comment: UI design should bend to user expectations, not vice-versa.

Comment: @Kevin Obviously, but I'm just pointing out the usual response to these requests. SE's pretty stubborn on this.